# How to obtain the current URL in R chromote?

Tags: r, chromote

I'm experimenting with the `chromote` package as a replacement for `RSelenium`. I see how to navigate to a particular URL, but I can't spot the command to use to obtain the current URL.  In `RSelenium` it was `getCurrentUrl()`; in `webdriver` it was `getUrl()`.

Is there an equivalent in `chromote`?

Here's what I've got:

```
library(chromote)
session <- ChromoteSession$new()
session$Page$navigate("https://stackoverflow.com")

# some clicks etc on the page

# Now where did I end up?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about a `chromote` method, though we can evaluate `window.location.href`:

```r
library(chromote)
session <- ChromoteSession$new()
{
  session$Page$navigate("https://stackoverflow.com")
  session$Page$loadEventFired()
} 
#> $timestamp
#> [1] 1683944
session$Runtime$evaluate("window.location.href")$result$value
#> [1] "https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Isn't `Page$navigate()` synchronous by default, so the `loadEventFired()` isn't needed?

Comment: Good question, I'm afraid I'm not able to provide an educated answer. I've been mostly following Chromote docs & examples when tinkering with it, e.g. https://github.com/rstudio/chromote/#taking-a-screenshot-of-a-web-page , and the use of `loadEventFired()` kind of stuck.

Comment: To my understanding, `navigate()` can still return before the page is loaded.